# What's the shortest way to generate a random IP address in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking, random

Just like the title says, wanted for testing purposes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use IPAddr

```
require 'ipaddr'
ipv4 = IPAddr.new(rand(2**32),Socket::AF_INET)
ipv6 = IPAddr.new(rand(2**128),Socket::AF_INET6)
```

Comment: Beware, that this can generate addresses starting with 0, which by all means (RFC3330) invalid.

Comment: since starting 0s are not ideal, I would rec the array answer below

Comment: To be on the safe side, this generates valid IPv4 addresses from the **10.x.x.x** private subnet: `IPAddr.new(10*2**24 + rand(2**24),Socket::AF_INET)`

Answer (score 19):

If you want a truly random IP address, `Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')` does it

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest using Faker

https://github.com/stympy/faker#fakerinternet

```
Faker::Internet.ip_v4_address #=> "24.29.18.175"
```

Comment: this is pretty awesome, actually....is it active and maintained.  Like that it has both IPv4 and 6 and URI.

Comment: While I am not deeply familiar with the library, I'd recommend `Faker` too. My primary reason is that this library appears to have been _created_ for your use case. [The docs](https://github.com/stympy/faker#fakerinternet) also suggest that it handles special IP addresses better too.

Answer (score 3):

```
ip = "%d.%d.%d.%d" % [rand(256), rand(256), rand(256), rand(256)]
```

Comment: That won't always generate a valid address. (On rare occasions, it could generate `0.0.0.0` or `255.255.255.255` which are not valid addresses)

Comment: Do those two addresses break some rule?  They look OK to me.  Since the OP only asked a vague question, those two are just as good as any other.

Comment: If I remember right, they are good IP numbers but are pre-assigned to network broadcasts. No machine can have an IP of 0.0.0.0 or 255.255.255.255, but they can respond to requests to those numbers. If that makes sense in an application then it's OK to use them. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this before to generate a random ip then validate it with Resolv

```
  ip = "#{rand(99)}.#{rand(100)}.#{rand(10)}.#{rand(255)}"
  begin
    if ip
      host = Resolv.new.getname(ip) 
      puts "#{c} #{real_ip.length} #{ip} #{host}" 
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "FAKE #{ip}"
  end
```

Comment: Uh this is probably the worst piece of code I've ever seen. Are you aware this does perform a ton of unnecessary DNS queries? A valid IP address doen't have to have a A record. This is wrong on so many levels.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to tack on to [Lass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465345/laas)'s comment with some code to get any safe [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) address, but not enough reputation yet.

So, if we take the following math results:

```
10*2**24 = 167772160
172*2**24 + 16*2**16 = 2886729728
192*2**24 + 168*2**16 = 3232235520
```

and, stuff them into an array which is stuffed in the IPAddr.new method

```
IPAddr.new([167772160, 2886729728, 3232235520].sample + rand(2**16), Socket::AF_INET)
```

Most any RF1918 space is generated.  Unfortunately, this will always produce 10.0.X.X addresses, but that should be fine for testing if one was looking for some address variety in a not too terrible looking one-liner format.

A major benefit of something like this or Lass's method over Faker is there is reduced risk for accidental taxing of someone's Internet resources if the code attempts to reach out to the random address for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To generate **valid** IP addresses within a reasonable network range (e.g. 10.0.0.0/24 or 2001:db8::/64), do this:

```
require 'ipaddr'
ipv4 = IPAddr.new("10.0.0.0/24", Socket::AF_INET) | IPAddr.new(rand(2**(32-24)),Socket::AF_INET)
ipv6 = IPAddr.new("2001:db8:cafe:babe::/64", Socket::AF_INET6) | IPAddr.new(rand(2**(128-64)),Socket::AF_INET6)
```

This can be generalized to any subnet:

```
subnet = "192.168.100.0"
prefix = 24
ipv4 = IPAddr.new("#{subnet}/#{prefix}", Socket::AF_INET) | IPAddr.new(rand(2**(32-prefix)),Socket::AF_INET)
```